# Best way to set state of object using dynamic key name? - reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a react state like:

```
this.state = {
  formInputs: {
    username: '',
    password: '',
    passwordConfirm: '',
  },
  handleChange = () => {
    const {target: {name, value}} = event;
    this.setState({
      [name as keyof formInputs]: value
    });
  }
};
```

How can I change this line ( [name as keyof formData]: value) to a JavaScript instead of Typescript?

Comment: Please post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for this or a codesandbox demo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use Computed property names concept to compute the object property name dynamically. For that we need to put the expression inside `[]`.

When you need to handle multiple controlled input elements, you can add a name attribute to each element and let the handler function choose what to do based on the value of event.target.name.

For your state

```
this.setState({
    formInput: {
        ...this.state.formInput,
        [event.target.name]: event.target.value
    }
})
```

Sandbox for your reference: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-basic-example-p7ft8

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

export default class Login extends Component {
  state = {
    formInputs: {
      email: "",
      password: ""
    }
  };

  handleOnChange = event => {
    this.setState({
      formInput: {
        ...this.state.formInput,
        [event.target.name]: event.target.value
      }
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <form>
        <label>Email</label>
        <input type="text" name="email" onChange={this.handleOnChange} />
        <label>Password</label>
        <input type="password" name="password" onChange={this.handleOnChange} />
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: what if you have form state object like:
state = {
formInput: {
username:"",
password: ""
}
would you still set it like this 
    handleOnChange = event => {     
        this.setState({
            [event.target.name]: event.target.value
        })
    }

Comment: I made a change to my answer for this question

Comment: I think my edit is also identical to what @Burak Gavas answered

Answer (score 2):

You can directly use [Bracket_notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Bracket_notation)

```
[name]: value
```

In your case, { formInput: { username:"", password: "" }

```
this.setState({
    formInput: {
        ...this.state.formInput,
        [name]: value
    }
});
```

Comment: I have tried that but it is binding the form data. for example I console the form state values are still null.

Comment: I think that you should put your handleChange function out of your state

Answer (score 0):

I think you can initialize your `formObject` as empty json and

```
this.state = {formInput: {}}
```

Later onChange you can set the value something like

```
this.setState({formInput[event.target.name]: event.target.value})
```

and conditionaly check if `(this.state.formInput.username) ? this.state.formInput.username : ''` to  value